# How to Send a MultipartForm Request

Tags: scala, playframework

I have constructed a multipart form with this type:

```scala
 val formData = MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile]
```

I want use WSClient to post this form data but the type that the post method takes is:

```scala
  def post(body: Source[MultipartFormData.Part[Source[ByteString, _]], _]): Future[Response]
```

How do I convert my formdata to match this type so I can use this post method?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-multipart/form-data ?

Comment: Yeah I did! But that is for a single file. I want post multiple files.

Comment: If you have a list of files, you can just map on it right?

    fileList.map { tmpFile =>
      ws.url(url).post(
        Source(
          FilePart(tmpFile.getName, tmpFile.getName, Option("text/plain"), FileIO.fromPath(tmpFile.toPath)) :: DataPart(
            "key",
            "value"
          ) :: List()
        )
      )
    }